# Are file name comments dangerous?

Tags: coldfusion

**TL;DR:** Is it wise to have HTML comments saying what CF file is displaying what HTML code? If not, why, and would a url variable with a db toggle be enough protection?

Here's more details:

Basically our code is old; everyone who coded or understood it is long gone. It was programmed with efficiency in mind over readability. Also through the years speed of development was valued over quality, so there's a lot of band-aids, duct tape, and comments are scarce and mostly useless.

There are these huge files which are mostly conditional logic used to figure out what HTML to display. In an effort to simplify them, I've replaced chunks of logic with includes. These includes contain HTML comments that say the name of the file so it's easy to locate while debugging. For instance:

```
<!-- display_center_column_content.cfm -->
```

As of now this is only in development, and I'm wondering if having this on production would be dangerous. If so, why, and would having a url variable with a database toggle be enough protection?

Comment: Why not use cfm comments <!--- ---> with three dashes intstead of two, these do not get sent with the page html

Comment: lharby, because they _want_ the HTML comments sent to the page - it's for debugging.

Comment: Travis, short answer: not really. Ideally you would refactor the code to be better organised, but in the absence of being able to do that, limiting the comments to a particular IP as well as using an obscure URL param to toggle the output should be ok. Simply outputting to everyone isn't in itself dangerous, but it does give an attacker more information - including that the codebase is difficult enough to manage to require them, which could be seen as something that makes it more likely that there are security flaws, and thus (for an attacker) a target worth concentrating on.

Comment: if your included .cfm files are in the web root then it tells an attacker that it's worth trying to request the files directly. Maybe a security check was only done higher up the chain of included files. Maybe the file uses an un-scoped variable, so I can request the file with ?foo=bar and get something untoward working. That said, it's of tremendous value when working with legacy codebases, so I'd use one fo the suggestions from @PeterBoughton and go for it.  You could also scope it to a particular user, if your site has an authentication mechanism

Comment: That's a good point - I forget some people put CFML files in the webroot. :/ If there are any there they should really be moved out, or at the very least have access blocked with htaccess/web.config/equivalent.

Comment: I'm wondering if `<cfinclude commentPath="true|false">` would make a sensible enhancement request? I could set request.commentPath however I want and use it to have CF insert the included template name. You could code it yourself, but it currently relies on remembering to add the path comment yourself each time and keeping it updated

Comment: With Railo you can do a custom built-in tag to wrap existing cfinclude, so no need to set the commentPath attribute everywhere.